# SimpleJdbcCall : How to Map/Send an Oracle Array of SQL Type which contains an array of another SQL Type to an Oracle Stored Procedure?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Here is my Bean Structure which i want to send to an oracle procedure ?

```
public class DMSApplicantIdScanningData {
    private String refId;
    private String applicantType;
    private String applicantName;
    private List<DMSDocument> dmsDocuments;
    //getter and setter methods
}

public class DMSDocument {
    private String documentName;
    private String category;
    private Date scannedDate;
    //Getter and Setter Methods
}
```

I want to send a List of  `DMSApplicantIdScanningData` as an input parameter to an oracle procedure?

So far i have tried this

```
this.saveScannedDataJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withCatalogName("PKG_DMS_RCU").
withProcedureName("PRC_SAVE_DMS_SCANNING_DATA").declareParameters(
    new SqlParameter("P_FAN_NO",Types.VARCHAR) ,
    new SqlParameter("P_DSA_NAME",Types.VARCHAR) ,
    new SqlParameter("P_BDM_NAME",Types.VARCHAR) ,
    new SqlParameter("P_FAN_NO",Types.VARCHAR) ,
    new SqlParameter("P_DMS_APPLICANT_SCANNING_ARRAY",OracleTypes.ARRAY,"T_DMS_APPLICANT_SCANNING_ARRAY"),
    new SqlOutParameter("P_MSG", Types.VARCHAR)
);
```

However this doesn't work.

If more information on problem is required then comment below

Answer (score 0):

I think you need follow with this project: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html.

Where your code should be like this:

```
ARRAY create(List<Map> data, String tableName, String recordName) {
        def recordKeys = internalProperties.getProperty(recordName.replaceFirst(/.*\./, '')).split(',')
        def connection = nativeConnection
        def structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(recordName, connection)

        def dataArray = []

        data.each { recordMap ->
            def record = []
            if (recordMap) {
                recordKeys.each {
                    record << recordMap[it]
                }
                dataArray << new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, record.toArray())
            }
        }

        new ARRAY(ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(tableName, connection), connection, dataArray.toArray())
    }
```

(sorry for Groovy code :-))

The idea is: create `STRUCT` for each list item and build `ARRAY` for the appropriate procedure parameter.